# How do I clear out all the saved entries in mapping?

Tags: solidity, cpp-ethereum

How do I clear out all the saved entries in mapping after the data is no longer useful

Answer (score 1):

We cannot loop though a mapping and hence have to store the keys in a separate array. Let's say you have a list of addresses and balances.

```
mapping(address => uint) balances;
address [] addresses;
```

You can reset all the balances by doing something like below.

```
function resetMapping(uint value) public {
    for (uint i=0; i< addresses.length ; i++){
        balances[addresses[i]] = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: any way to clear out a mapping entirely